# Javascript not writing to page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using both php and javascript to create a repository page I'm working on and so far the table I'm generating through jQuery isn't actually writing to the page. All the console logs work fine but nothing else.

I currently have it working so the php file that is open calls another which has the javascript in (and the base of the table).

The PHP file that is called looks like this:

```
<script>
    var h = ['Black Panther', 'Black Widow', 'Cable', 'Captain America', 'Colossus', 'Cyclops', 'Daredevil', 'Deadpool', 'Emma Frost', 'Gambit',
                'Ghost Rider', 'Hawkeye', 'Hulk', 'Human Torch', 'Iron Man', 'Jean Grey', 'Loki', 'Luke Cage', 'Moon Knight', 'Ms Marvel', 'Nightcrawler',
                'Punisher', 'Rocket Raccoon', 'Scarlet Witch', 'Spider-Man', 'Squirrel Girl', 'Storm', 'Thing', 'Thor', 'Wolverine'];

    var v = ['Black Cat', 'Blob', 'Bullseye', 'Dr. Doom', 'Dr. Octopus', 'Electro', 'Elektra', 'Gorgon', 'Green Goblin', 'Grim Reaper', 'Hood',
                'Juggernaut', 'Kingpin', 'Kurse', 'Lady Deathstrike', 'Living Laser', 'Loki', 'Madame Hydra', 'Magneto', 'Malekith', 'Mandarin',
                'Mister Sinister', 'M.O.D.O.K.', 'Moleman', 'Pyro', 'Rhino', 'Sabretooth', 'Shocker', 'Taskmaster', 'Tombstone', 'Venom', 'Wizard'];

    var e = ['Brood', 'Cliffwalker Tribe', 'Dark Elves', 'Frost Giants', 'Hand', 'Hydra', 'Latverian Drones', 'Maggia', 'Mercenary', 'N\'Garai Demons',
                'Purifier', 'Rock Trolls', 'Serpent Men', 'Storm Giants', 'Toad'];

    var i, table = $('tbody');


    for(i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        $row = $('<tr id="row' + i + '"></tr>');
        $row.append('<td onclick="location.href=\'?s=' + v[i].toLowerCase().replace(' ','') + '\'">' + v[i] + '</td>');
        console.log( 'Villain Added: ' + v[i] );
        if(i > 29) { table.append($row);continue; }
        $row.prepend('<td onclick="location.href=\'?s=' + h[i].toLowerCase().replace(' ','') + '\'">' + h[i] + '</td>');
        console.log( 'Hero Added: ' + h[i] );
        if(i > 14) { table.append($row);continue; }
        $row.append('<td onclick="location.href=\'?s=' + e[i].toLowerCase().replace(' ','') + '\'">' + e[i] + '</td>');
        console.log( 'Enemy Added: ' + e[i] );

        table.append($row);
    }

</script>

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <th>Heroes</th>
        <th>Villains</th>
        <th>Enemies</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The page shows that exact code when I view the source of the page. The tbody element is empty when it should have had everything written to it.

My question is, is there something I'm doing wrong? I'm really new to PHP and am only using it to make it easier for me to organise my code. I've tried placing the actual function after the table is created, putting it in a document load function (which shouldn't change anything) and nothing is worked.

Please help me solve this issue. Cheers.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/8958S/

Comment: @Christoph Other than the fact the Venom and Wizard are in the Heroes list rather than the Villains list.

Comment: Move the script after the table and it will work fine :)

Comment: @Spedwards take a look at my answer, i explained, why your elements are shifted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must include all your js inside the ready method

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
     // your code here
});
```

or you create a js method and invoke that on onload event of body so that the code gets executed *after* your table is added to the DOM tree.

Comment: This works. It's strange because I did this (except the variables weren't in the function other than `i` and `table`) and it didn't work. Wouldn't have thought it would matter. Maybe I had forgotten to update my server.

New problem however, Venom & Wizard are now in the Heroes list.

Comment: This is the right answer, so you should mark it. For any new problems / questions you should create a new topic by doing so you'll be helping others and also playing your part in SO.

Comment: @Zubair1 It doesn't let you mark an answer for about 8-10 minutes so I was waiting for that. I had full intentions to mark it. As for the new question, I know what to do :P

Answer (score 0):

When you view the source of the page, you will not find the newly (dynamically) added elements.
For looking at them try to use `document.documentElement.innerHTML`  this will give you the current html of the page.

View source only shows the page source when it was rendered from the server, i.e. the original source of the page and not the version which was modified later on using javascript.

Comment: By viewsource I meant that I inspected the element which is the same as that but much, much neater.